# Oracle - How to count average of attendance on based on concert itself?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

How to count an average of attendance based on concert_id?

So far what i have done is like this

```
select concert_id, event_id, count(customer_id) attendance,
case when concert_id = 1
   then (select count(customer_id)/count(concert_id) 
   from booking where concert_id=1) 
   end as avg_attendance_each_concert
from booking
group by event_id, concert_id
order by event_id;
```

result

```
CONCERT_ID   EVENT_ID ATTENDANCE AVG_ATTENDANCE_EACH_CONCERT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------
         1          1          1                           3
         1          2          2                           3
         2          3          2
         2          4          1
         3          5          2
         3          6          2
         4          8          2
         4          9          2
         5         11          4
         5         12          1
         5         13          1
```

How to make AVG_ATTENDANCE_EACH_CONCERT become like this?

```
CONCERT_ID   EVENT_ID ATTENDANCE AVG_ATTENDANCE_EACH_CONCERT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------
         1          1          1                         1.5 --> 3 attendance / 2 same concert_id
         1          2          2                         1.5
         2          3          2                         1.5 --> 3 attendance / 2 same concert_id
         2          4          1                         1.5
         3          5          2                         2 --> 4 attendance / 2 same concert_id
         3          6          2                         2
         4          8          2                         2 --> 4 attendance / 2 same concert_id
         4          9          2                         2
         5         11          4                         2 --> 6 attendance / 3 same concert_id
         5         12          1                         2
         5         13          1                         2
```

Because I would like to show which event have below average attendance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about AVG in its analytic form?

(By the way, your example for CONCERT_ID = 5 is wrong; 6 / 3 = 2, not 3).

```
SQL> with booking (concert_id, event_id, customer_id) as
  2  (select 1, 1, 10 from dual union
  3   select 1, 2, 10 from dual union
  4   select 1, 2, 20 from dual union
  5   --
  6   select 3, 5, 10 from dual union
  7   select 3, 5, 20 from dual union
  8   select 3, 6, 30 from dual union
  9   select 3, 6, 40 from dual union
 10   --
 11   select 5, 11, 10 from dual union
 12   select 5, 11, 20 from dual union
 13   select 5, 11, 30 from dual union
 14   select 5, 11, 40 from dual union
 15   select 5, 12, 50 from dual union
 16   select 5, 13, 60 from dual
 17  )
 18  select concert_id, event_id, count(customer_id) attendance,
 19    avg(count(*)) over (partition by concert_id) avg_attendance_each_concert
 20  from booking
 21  group by concert_id, event_id
 22  order by event_id;

CONCERT_ID   EVENT_ID ATTENDANCE AVG_ATTENDANCE_EACH_CONCERT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------
         1          1          1                         1,5
         1          2          2                         1,5
         3          5          2                           2
         3          6          2                           2
         5         11          4                           2
         5         12          1                           2
         5         13          1                           2

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: wow working like magic. 
never heard about analytic sir. How to use over (partition by column_name)?

what i am confusing is partition by clause sir

Comment: @sekti92 - see documentation for [Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm).